# Getting data that is stored in several HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, typeahead.js

Let's say I have like 10 spans at the beginning of page's `body` with a structure like this:

(Just to reach it easier with Jquery, didn't know how to pass an array with JSON)

`<span class="nike" data-img="logos/nike_logo.png" data-id="10"></span>`

EDIT!: The spans can be changed into anything else, inputs etc. and the structure can be changed, only need to reach the img url and the id

Now, there's a Javascript function that goes through an array of words, and prints them out (search/suggestion/typeahead kind of thing). Example of the function:

```
function suggestionTemplate(context) {

            switch(displayFn(context)) {

                case "nike":

                    return "<p style='background-image:url(logos/nike_logo.png);'>" 
                            + displayFn(context) + "</p>";
                    break;

                case "spalding":

                    return "<p style='background-image:url(logos/spalding_logo.png);'>" 
                    + displayFn(context) + "</p>";

                    break;

                default:
                    return "<p>" + displayFn(context) + "</p>";
            }

}
```

So the question, how can I make this function get all the  `span`  class names (or it can be data-name etc.), and then when `displayFn(context) ==` one of the span's class names return the `<p>` element with that span's `data-img` ?

Please tell me if it's too hard to understand. I'm just making kind of an experiment and would like to know if this is possible to do.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Top answer to "How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/3816975)

Comment: I know, I've checked that out already. Decided to skip it and just get it working the 'dumb way' first.

Comment: it would be much easier to help you if you could make a jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the structure like this, it would be much easier:

```
<span class="js-app-data" data-name="nike" data-img="logos/nike_logo.png" data-id="10"></span>
```

Then you can get all the data you defined like this:

```
data = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-app-data'), function(mem, e){
    mem[e.dataset.name] = {
        img: e.dataset.img,
        id: e.dataset.id
    }
    return mem
}, {})
```

This will make `data` an object with structure like this:

```
{nike: {img:'logos/nike_logo.png', id:'10'}, ...}
```

From that, it should be easy to get the data from javascript.

```
function suggestionTemplate(context) {
    if (context.name in data) {
        return ("<p style='background-image:url("+ data[context.name].img +");'>" 
                + context.name + "</p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you tell me how do I use the function you gave though? The function I mentioned `suggestionTemplate` is called everytime a letter is entered, so do  I put your function inside that one? EDIT: the ',' fixed that error, however now 'data' is undefined.

Comment: @GytisK I missed a comma, and I added a function that returns a `<p>` with the right background.

Comment: Well, I've got the values now :) However I don't think `(context in data)` is going to work, since the `console.log(context)` on every click has this: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0173tbided

Comment: @GytisK Oh, I had assumed that `context` is going to be a simple string.

Comment: Well, how could I reach the values of `data` to compare with `context` ? Data looks like this http://awesomescreenshot.com/08e3tbj2a1. It only has to find same names like efx = efx, not efx = efx blabla

Comment: Omg it works! You're a genius. Thanks for taking your time to help me with this random as hell code :)